# ConcurrentQueue ToList() vs ToArray().ToList()

Tags: c#, linq, concurrency

I'm not 100% on this, so I want an expert's input.

```
ConcurrentQueue<object> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<object>();

List<object> listA = queue.ToArray().ToList();   // A
List<object> listB = queue.ToList();             // B
```

I understand that `ToArray()` method will make a copy (as it is an internal method within `ConcurrentQueue`), but will calling the `ToList()` method directly do the same thing?

**Simply, is it safe to refactor code from A to B?**

Comment: Hold the mouse cursor over `.ToList()`, is it shown as an instance method on the queue, or as an extension method from Enumerable?

Comment: Unless you're adding or removing items from the resulting list (or passing to a method or property that requires a list) you could always just use the array.

Comment: Keep in mind that accepted answer depends on internals of ToList, which is generally not thread safe. For example if you will do the same with ConcurrentDictionary - it will be not safe and might throw exception. So I mean better not make a habit of it, since ConcurrentQueue is kind of lucky case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we look to the source code we wiil see that GetEnumerator is thread safe also, so I supose A and B are threadsafe both.

When you call .ToList() Linq call to constructor of List

```
 public List(IEnumerable<T> collection) {
```

so the code are actually make a copy looks like a thread safe:

```
        using(IEnumerator<T> en = collection.GetEnumerator()) {
            while(en.MoveNext()) {
                Add(en.Current);                                    
            }
```

[source code of ConcurrentQueue](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs,18bcbcbdddbcfdcb)

[source code of List](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646)

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    // Increments the number of active snapshot takers. This increment must happen before the snapshot is 
    // taken. At the same time, Decrement must happen after the enumeration is over. Only in this way, can it
    // eliminate race condition when Segment.TryRemove() checks whether m_numSnapshotTakers == 0. 
    Interlocked.Increment(ref m_numSnapshotTakers);

    // Takes a snapshot of the queue. 
    // A design flaw here: if a Thread.Abort() happens, we cannot decrement m_numSnapshotTakers. But we cannot 
    // wrap the following with a try/finally block, otherwise the decrement will happen before the yield return 
    // statements in the GetEnumerator (head, tail, headLow, tailHigh) method.           
    Segment head, tail;
    int headLow, tailHigh;
    GetHeadTailPositions(out head, out tail, out headLow, out tailHigh);

    //If we put yield-return here, the iterator will be lazily evaluated. As a result a snapshot of
    // the queue is not taken when GetEnumerator is initialized but when MoveNext() is first called.
    // This is inconsistent with existing generic collections. In order to prevent it, we capture the 
    // value of m_head in a buffer and call out to a helper method.
    //The old way of doing this was to return the ToList().GetEnumerator(), but ToList() was an 
    // unnecessary perfomance hit.
    return GetEnumerator(head, tail, headLow, tailHigh);
}
```

remarks of the enumerator also says that we can use it concurently:

```
    /// The enumeration represents a moment-in-time snapshot of the contents
    /// of the queue.  It does not reflect any updates to the collection after 
    /// <see cref="GetEnumerator"/> was called.  The enumerator is safe to use
    /// concurrently with reads from and writes to the queue.
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you are saying that refactoring from A to B is okay, since they are both accomplishing the same task while remaining thread-safe?

Comment: @Svek, yes they are thread safe, you can safely replace one by another